# What is this process "ctfprocdca.exe" doing on my machine?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus, anti-spyware

I found this process on my working machine (win7 64bit), installed at location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Products\Input Processor\ctfprocdca.exe

The process name may vary a bit. I try to google its purpose, but found very little information about it. Someone say it is a corporate spyware, is it so?

Comment: look at the file versions. Does it show any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of Mendiant Intelligent Response agent. You can read more about it on [Mendiant's web page](https://www.mandiant.com/products/mandiant-platform/intelligent-response).

Comment: Thank you.  At least now I know what's that thing that misbehaves by going to as much CPU as it can grab on occasion.